# How to create mysql find query with hasmany() cross/opposite relation in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I have below mysql tables:

Table1: emp

Fields: id, document_ids

Table2: documents

Fields: id, document_name

Example data:

Table1

```html
emp
<table border='1pt'>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>document_ids</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>[1,2]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>[2,3]</td>
  </tr>  
</table>

documents
<table border='1pt'>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>document_name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Matser Degree</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>HSC</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>SSC</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Result should be:

<table border='1pt'>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>documents</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Master Degree, HSC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>HSC,SSC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the result that I printed in above third table as a result.
Relation should be on first model 'emp' only. How do I make query to get such result in yii2 model relation?

Answer (score 0):

It depends which database u use. [Yii2 ActiveRelationTrait enhancement](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1249) - here guys added support to get relation by array, use it normally like other `hasMany()` relations.

And if youre using database which doesnt support this you can do something like this, if `document_ids` is real PHP array:

```
public function getDocuments() {
   return Document()->find()->andWhere(['id' => $this->document_ids]);
}
```